# Telegraph circuit confusion

Tags: diodes, bidirectional

I know little about this stuff, but I bought two old telegraph keys and two sounders.  They polish up beautifully. I’d like to get them working in two remote locations in my house.

Each location will have have a key, sounder and local battery, likely 1.5V each.  The telegraph system used one conductor with an earth ground.

My guess is to accomplish bidirectional traffic on the other conductor, I assume I will need diodes to close the circuit at each the key when the remote key is switched.

I could sure use a recommendation as to how to accomplish this.

Comment: Data sheets or specifications of the sounder are required. How many wires do you plan to run? When you say bidirectional, do you mean half-duplex?

Comment: There were no diodes available back when telegraphs were developed, yet they operated properly with multiple keys and sounders.  You shouldn't need diodes for your setup, either.

Comment: Just wire the sounders in parallel. When any key is pressed, all of the sounders will sound. (Additionally: when more than one key is pressed at the same time, it means those batteries are in parallel. Probably won't cause any problem, but don't quote me on that. That could be averted by putting a diode in series with each *battery*)

Answer (score 1):

The following is from the 1911 *Encylopaedia Britannica* article "Telegraph".  (K=key, B=battery, I=indicator, E=Earth,, L=line, G=galvanometer to see outgoing signal.)

[image]

If you're just connected up two places in a house, consider running signal and ground, as follows.  For the lamp, use your sounders; for the batteries, whatever makes your sounders sound.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f40jIO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: the keys appear to be SPDT in the top schematic

Comment: @jsotola yes, in the old circuit they disconnected the local indicator, when you're keying.  The second diagram shows on both the remote and local indicator when either side keys.  It's a choice.